# Configure HAProxy with Apache and Tomcat servers

Tags: load-balancing, tomcat, haproxy, high-availability

I want to configure HAProxy with Apache and Tomcat Servers. My current application structure is Apache -> Tomcat. I need to configure HAProxy above Apache which is HAProxy -> Apache -> Tomcat [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B9nS.jpg)
. I am configuring HAProxy above Apache to add load balancing using multiple load balancers.

Can anyone help me on how to configure this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Here is pretty much the same scenario: https://www.unixmen.com/configure-high-available-load-balancer-haproxy-keepalived/

Comment: Do you have a base configuration for haproxy you can share, and maybe some specific issues you are having in trying to set things up the way you want? There isn't a lot of indication you've [done much research](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask), and a more specific question/issue might get more useful answers.

Comment: What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? What does your config look like? Do you have any log entries from the times it didn't work as expected?